# How to upload my files to my new vps linux server?

Tags: linux, ftp, connection, upload

I just installed Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) x64 with LAMP on my VPS server. How can I connect to the server using FTP to upload my files?

Answer (score 5):

Do you connect using SSH? If so...use filezilla on your client desktop. No need to install anything on the server. Connect to the server on port 22 (not 21).

http://filezilla-project.org/download.php

Comment: No need to setup a user first on the server side? What will be my username and password when I'm trying to connect?

Comment: +1 Much easer than my Idea.

Comment: @Maxxon Root and whatever your root Password.

Comment: Oh, thanks! This is working. But why port 22 and not 21? Port 21 really does not work.

Comment: Not sure why you didn't have to specify SFTP, but if it works good :) The reason port 21 isn't working is that it requires an FTP service to be configured and a user setup with access to FTP (root usually can't by default). SFTP (port 22) actually emulates FTP by running the commands over SSH.

Answer (score 1):

You more than likely unless it is  already setup install an FTP server I'd suggest [ProFTP](http://www.proftpd.org/) did your VPS come with an control panel or just SSH? If t came with no control panel take a look at [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/). Both of those are free.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I got an embedded terminal/console stuff. I'm also able to install ispmanager for free which is a control panel. But now I am curious how to make it from terminal? Do I need to install an FTP server, or is it already installed? If so, how can I access it from my desktop computer?

Comment: Its doubtful its installed, I'd install webmin first and that will install your FTP, what OS do you run?

Comment: @Jacob see question(Ubuntu 10.04)

Comment: Are you asking my desktop OS or server OS ? I'm running Mac OS X Snow Leopard on my Macbook Pro, but I run Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) x64 with LAMP on my vps server.

Comment: Do I need to make a user first on my server to be able to connect it with ftp?

Comment: Use the guide here to install webmin http://www.webmin.com/deb.html

Comment: You can, but webmin will make it easier